# DataTables warning: table id=Customers - Requested unknown parameter 'Name' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, api, datatables, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to load data from api to my datatable in view.so I utilized ajax and pass my table id to datatable. I have a property Name in both api and model but I don't know why I get this error while I run my code. This is main part which related to my issue in view:

```
<table id="Customers" class=" table-hover"> @*table table-bordered*@
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>Discount Rate</th>
                <th>Delete </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

@section scripts

    {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Customers").DataTable({

            ajax: {
                url: "/api/customer",
                dataSrc: ""
            },

           columns: [
                {
                data: "Name",
                render: function (data, type, customers) {
                    return "<a href='/customer/edit/" + customers.CustomerID + ">" + data + "</a>"

                }

            },

            {
                data: "Name"
            },
            {
                data: "CustomerID",
                render: function (data, type, Customers)
                {
                    return "<button clasee='btn-link js-delete' data-customer-id=" + Customers.CustomerID + ">delete</button>"

                }
            }      

           ]
        });
...
```

And this is my api class:

```
 public class CustomerDto
    {

        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; } //here is name property!


        [MinAge18Requierd]
        public DateTime? birthday { get; set; }
        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }

        public byte MembershipTypeID { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is api controller:

```
 public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
        private IdentityModels _context;

        public CustomerController()
        {
            _context = new IdentityModels();
        }
        public IEnumerable<CustomerDto> GetCustomer()
            {
            var customer = _context.customers.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<Customers, CustomerDto>);
            return customer;

            }
        public CustomerDto GetCustomer(int id)
        {
            var Customer = _context.customers.SingleOrDefault(m => m.CustomerID == id);
            if (Customer == null)

                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            return Mapper.Map<Customers,CustomerDto>(Customer);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public CustomerDto CreateCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)

               throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            var customer= Mapper.Map<CustomerDto, Customers>(customerDto);
            _context.customers.Add(customer);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            customerDto.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID;
            //customerDto.birthday = customer.birthday;
            //customerDto.Name = customer.Name;
            //customerDto.IsSubscribedToNewsletter = customerDto.IsSubscribedToNewsletter;
            //customerDto.MembershipTypeID = customer.MembershipTypeID;
            return customerDto;
        }
        [HttpPut]
        public  void UpdateCustomer(int id,CustomerDto customerDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            }
            var _Customer = _context.customers.SingleOrDefault(m => m.CustomerID == id);

            if (_Customer==null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            Mapper.Map(customerDto,_Customer);
            //_Customer.Name = customer.Name;
            //_Customer.MembershipTypeID = customer.MembershipTypeID;
            //_Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter = customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter;
            //_Customer.birthday = customer.birthday;
            //_context.SaveChanges();
        }
        [HttpDelete]
        public void DeleteCustomer(int id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            }
            var _Customer = _context.customers.SingleOrDefault(m => m.CustomerID == id);

            if (_Customer == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            _context.customers.Remove(_Customer);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

I get this error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=Customers - Requested unknown parameter 'Name' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error
```

I don't get why I get this error.
TIA

Comment: Can you show us the json response that you are getting from `/api/customer`

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal as your comment I checked there and I found the answer thanks for contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a lot I get that the problem is related to the to this part:

```
columns: [
                {
                data: "Name",
                render: function (data, type, customers) {
                    return "<a href='/customer/edit/" + customers.CustomerID + ">" + data + "</a>"

                }
```

I understood when I use Camel notation I have to pass data a parameter which begin with lowercase. that means my code should only change here:

```
data: "name" //instead of "Name"
```

Because my datasrc return a list of json objects with camel notation format.
hope this post can help someone who stuck in this kind of problem.